# How to ignore Out-of-line definition error in Xcode with LLVM 4.1

Tags: c++, macos, llvm

I am getting a compiler error with LLVM 4.1:

```
/Users/vibhor/src/mam/client_daemon/source/core/_osx/UtilSystem_OSX.cpp:261:32: Out-of-line definition of 'what' does not match any declaration in 'std::bad_typeid'
```

for the following code:

```
const char* ::std::bad_typeid::what() const throw() { return NULL; }
```

Is there a way to suppress this? It compiles fine with GCC.

Comment: Without being given more of the context, it's kinda hard. What's the definition of `bad_typeid` ? Maybe it's just that there is a mismatch...

Answer (score 0):

My original answer, which was to try compiling with a different stdlib was completely off base.

It looks like an attempt to compile against the 10.5 SDK, which has a different bad_typeid than expected. The workaround is a guard around the definition:

```
#if defined(MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_6) && MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_6
const char* ::std::bad_typeid::what() const throw() { return NULL; }
#endif
```

Comment: This code is a workaround for a bug in the 10.6 SDK - http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2010/May/msg00183.html so it sounds like you're compiling against the 10.5 or earlier SDK, which *does not* have the same definition of bad_typeid (i.e. it doesn't have the what() declaration). I'll update the answer with the recommended workaround from the message

Comment: And even more awesome if you look at the `typeinfo` header in 10.8, it looks like the `::what` declaration is guarded by an `__TARGETING_4_0_DYLIB` ifdef

Comment: You are right, this is a work around for the code to work on 10.5.